# Ищу python библиотеку для распознавания ключевой фразы, аналог snowboy

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, распознавание-речи

Есть довольно хорошая библиотека - snowboy (https://pypi.org/project/snowboy/ и https://github.com/seasalt-ai/snowboy), но у неё отсутствует поддержка Windows, и у меня так и не получилось установить её на Linux. Помогите найти её аналоги для python3. Также нужна поддержка Raspberry Pi.

Comment: вот эта штука не подойдёт ? https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: Нет, оно постоянно распознаёт речь и отправляет её на сервер. Мне же нужно оффлайн детектить одну фразу активации. Также забыл добавить, у библиотеки должен быть инструментарий для создания модели со своей фразой активации, как у snowboy.